# Mails sent via smtp.gmail.com or Google Client API and DKIM

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-schemas, google-client

I'm currently experimenting with [Google Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/) sent via PHP. I'm letting users authenticate using `Google_Service_Oauth2` and then send a mail from their mail account to themselves using `Google_Service_Gmail` and `users_messages->send('me', $encodedMessage)`.

The markup itself checks out valid in the [Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/). And `HotelReservation` and `FlightReservation` types even show up fine in Inbox. But all other types don't show up as cards.

After poking around I found a few comments that this might be because of a missing DKIM signature in those mails. And yes, when I send the exact same HTML (I'm using Microdata markup.) using the [Gmail Actions Tester](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/), the mails have DKIM signatures and the cards appear as expected.

This is, although the [Markup documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema) clearly states:

> All emails where the sender and the recipient are the same account ignore the registration requirements and can be used for self-testing.

And I didn't want to setup some mail proxy in Google Apps Engine just to get that DKIM signature.

So how can I send mails to myself using `smtp.gmail.com` or the Google Client API **and** get a DKIM signature added by GMail?

Comment: I've run into the same problem, no resolution yet.

Comment: You may be able to achieve it using Google Scripts... follow the tutorial here https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial and you may be able to create and publish an API using that (look at the publish option in the menu).  Not certain it would work exactly as you want but perhaps worth exploring.

Comment: @Clay Yes, this works fine via script.google.com, however, that's not what I want. I want it self-hosted.